# Is it possible to submit data to database from a XML(rss)?

Tags: rss

I want to allow users to post comments on RSS page and the data will be saved in the database using a form.
I want to know if it is possible to submit data to database from a XML(rss) file.

I need help and guidance in this issue.

Comment: Typos and grammatical error fixed.

Comment: Question restructured.